# How to find out "InnoDB Write buffer efficiency"?

Tags: mysql, innodb, performance, performance-testing, performance-tuning

Is there any way to find out that "InnoDB Write buffer efficiency" without tools like `mysqltuner`?

I can't find it in `INNODB STATUS` or `information_schema`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need to know it?  There is no actionable information in the statistic.

Make `innodb_buffer_pool_size` about 70% of *available* RAM (assuming more than 4GB of RAM); that will be optimal.

Look for slow queries and improve them; that will cut back on performance problems.

Here are some things you can get from `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` and `SHOW VARIABLES`:

- `Innodb_pages_written / Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests` -- Write requests that had to hit disk -- <15% is 'good'
- `Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free / Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests` -- Should not have to wait to get into the buffer pool. -- <1% is 'good'
- `Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed / Uptime` -- Writes actually going to disk
- `Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed / max(Questions, Queries)` -- Buffer pool writes per query

Answer (score 2):

When you issue the command `show engine innodb status\G` you will see a fair amount of information. You want to look for something that looks like `Buffer pool hit rate 900 / 1000` in the output.

Your efficiency rate will be the percentage of hits compared to the overall usage. In the example above, my efficiency is 90% (900/1000).

Comment: is that the hit rate for read or write or both together? I need it separate for read and write.